# How to add a class to each TD in a TR when the TR gets selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using HTML, PHP and JS to create a report website. I've got several table that I'm showing. In each table there are multiple rows `tr` with many columns `td`. I have it setup so that when I click on one of the `tr` it gets the class of `selected`. I also have it setup so that the `td` that is clicked in gets the class of `selectedtd`. What I want is to have all the `td` in the `tr` that gets selected to have the class `selectedtd` and then to have that class removed when the `tr` is unselected. Here's what I've got so far:

This script updates the `tr` to either have the class or remove it when anywhere in the `tr` is clicked.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $("#UpdateTable tr").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

This script adds or removes the class `selectedtd` to an individual `td` when it is clicked.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $("#UpdateTable td").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).removeClass('selectedtd');
        $(this).toggleClass('selectedtd')
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to get these to update all the `td` in the selected `tr` to have the class `selectedtd`.

Comment: Just a quick question, given that you know which row has been selected and you apply a class, is there a reason (other than styling) that you need to apply this to every td in a selected row?

Comment: @Corporalis each `td` is in a `div` so to get the styling that I want to work I need to have all the `td` to have the correct class. So, no it's just for styling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As required `tr` is already selected, just use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the `td`'s within the selected `tr`.

Try below code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //< ![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    $("#UpdateTable tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected').find('td').toggleClass('selectedtd');
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

---

**Complete Example:**

```css
td.selectedtd {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //< ![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    $("#UpdateTable tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected').find('td').toggleClass('selectedtd');
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>

<table id="UpdateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. This works for me. Will mark as the answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks

Comment: it was downvoted because it doesnt remove the class of the other td's. check the other snippets

Comment: But this is what user is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting closest table, select closest `tr` and do stuff than:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('td').click(function () {
    // first remove all classes
    $('td, tr').removeClass('selectedtd selected active');
    
    // $(this) shows to currently clicked TD
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('active');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').addClass('selectedtd');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
})
```

```css
td {
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  }

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.selectedtd {
  color: #000;
}
.selected {
  color: #0d0;
}
.active {
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily in just one script:

```js
$("#UpdateTable tr").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').children().removeClass('selectedtd');
   $(this).children().toggleClass('selectedtd');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  }
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  }

tr.selected {
  color: white;
  }

td.selectedtd {
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="UpdateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>    
    <td>1.2</td>    
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>    
    <td>2.2</td>    
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>    
    <td>3.2</td>    
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').click(function(el){
  // Removes the already selected
  $('.selecetedtd').removeClass('selecetedtd');

  // Selects current row
  $(this).parents('tr')
    .toggleClass('selecetedtd');
});
```

You can see the example in use [here](http://jsbin.com/leqodo/edit?js,output).

Answer (score 1):

Here.

```js
$("#UpdateTable tr").click(function ()
{              
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
      $(this).addClass('selectedtd');
    });
  
    $(this).siblings('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td').removeClass('selectedtd');
    });
    
});
```

```css
.selectedtd{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="UpdateTable">
  <tr>
    <td>TD 1</td>
    <td>TD 2</td>
    <td>TD 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 4</td>
    <td>TD 5</td>
    <td>TD 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 7</td>
    <td>TD 8</td>
    <td>TD 9</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you can massively simplify this:

```
$('#UpdateTable').on('click', 'td', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected').children().toggleClass('selectedtd');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vr30z7qx/1/

Comment: This doesn't work the way that I would like. I want to update all the `td` in the `tr` that is selected to have the class `selectedtd`. This doesn't seem to be doing that. Sometimes it will and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Edited. Any time you're applying a class to ALL elements under a common parent you probably want to revise your approach. Without knowing your precise situation I can't elaborate, but it's likely this is unnecessary - the parent has the class, so you should be able to select tds based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each()`  function

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        $row.find("td").each(function()
        {
                $(this).text("fffff");    
          $(this).addClass("fffff");    
        }
        ); 

    });
```

here is the working fiddle 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/1967/)